# check if floating point variable has 'normal' values

Tags: c, floating-point

how can i check if a floating point value is a normal number and does not have any crude states (+-inf, ind, nan, qnan, denormal ...).

Checking for identity with it self seems to work for nan, but the other states?

Sorry - i forgot to mention that I am tied to an C90 Compiler ;(

Comment: If you search among the [common mathematicl functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math) in the standard library, I'm sure you could find something. For example [`isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) to check if a value is NaN.

Comment: does your `math.h` have `fpclassify`?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin fpclassify is not part of C90

Answer (score 4):

You can use `isnormal` macro:

```
#include <math.h>
int isnormal(real-floating x);
```

There are also `isfinite`, `isinf` and `isnan` macros.

Comment: i appended the c90 constraint

Comment: @vlad_tepesch The edit was done after my answer; c90 does not have these macros, I suggest you to take an implementation of `fpclassify` from a small libc like musl, and check for `FP_NORMAL`return value (assuming you are also using IEEE-754).

Comment: yes this is the way i will do it. but i am not that happy with that because the code is used on different platforms and even on different processor architectures.