# Check if floating point number is normal in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

Are there any python library functions that discriminate between regular floating point numbers, and all of the atypical ones, NaN, +/-Inf, denormal etc.?

Essentially, I'm asking the Python version of this question: [check if floating point variable has 'normal' values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30914865/1497199)

Comment: wouldn't `isinf`, `isfinite` and `isnan` of `math` package suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if a float `x` is finite, just use [`math.isfinite(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isfinite).

To check if a float `x` is denormal (subnormal), here is a possible snippet:

```
import numpy
x = 1.0e-320
fmin_normalized = numpy.finfo(type(x)).tiny
x_is_subnormal =  numpy.isfinite(x) and x!= 0 and abs(x) < fmin_normalized
print(x_is_subnormal)
```

I let you finish the work (write the appropriate lambda and filter the collection)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
As pointed out, my previous reply didn't quite work and I'm unsure of a clean method of doing this.
So I guess you would have to pick out the types you would like to remove like so:

```
test = [4, 4e99, 0b0101, 3.2, np.nan, 6, np.nan, np.inf]

result = []
for value in test:
    if not np.isnan(value) and np.isfinite(value):
        result.append(value)

print(result)

OUTPUT:
[4, 4e+99, 5, 3.2, 6]
```

Comment: Testing this with online Python services, e.g., [Python 3.7.4 at Jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online/), shows that “4” and “6” pass but “3.2”, “-5”, and “4e99” do not. What version of Python did you use to get the output you show?

Comment: How could it possibly work for 3.2 since `".".isnumeric()` is false? same for negative numbers like str(-4).isnumeric(). Does this snippet really work as advertised?

Comment: Note that `math.isfinite(float('nan'))` is false, so code could be further simplified. Remain to see how to detect subnormals...